# TYPO3 felogin/femanager use email field as username

Tags: typo3, typoscript

When a user updates his profile (email) I want that the username gets updated too.

I didn't find the configuration to achieve it.

Thank you!

Comment: which extension do you use for editing the user profile? The answer might vary depending on the extension.

Comment: I'm using femanager

Comment: the extension sr_feuser_regiser had an option `useEmailAsUsername` where you (also) could login with your email address. you might inspect that extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the option `fillEmailWithUsername` for this, see the [docs of femanager](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/femanager/Installation/Index.html).

Comment: ... and let the user edit his username instead of email.

Comment: And is there a similar configuration for TYPO3? I mean when creating a feuser in BE I and the end user don't want to fill username field AND email field.

Comment: there is no such option. you could implement a hook which persists the email address in the other field

Comment: And don't forget to disable the email validation in the typoscript setup plugin.tx_femanager.settings.new.validation.email.required = 0